# Android Layout Transition Animation When Removing Then Adding The Same Child

Tags: android, animation, drag-and-drop

**Scenario:**
I am creating a drag and drop feature within a linear layout. It is a very simple layout: one LinearLayout at the root and many Views within (for testing purposes they are just instances of the View class with different coloured backgrounds). I have created the system, you can 'pick-up' a View which is caused by a long click on one of the child views. This creates the drag shadow and at this point I call removeView() on the container to give the impression that the view has been picked up. I keep this view in memory. As the view is dragged around, a placeholder view is moved around to show the eventaul drop place for your drag location if you were to let go of the dragged shadow. This also works well and the removed view is then added back at the index where the placeholder was.

**Problem:**
When enabling 'android:animateLayoutChanges', the animations make this whole process look a whole lot smoother. The one artifact created by this is that when the dragged view is dropped (the same view that was removed when the drag started gets added back into the container) shows a transition animation from the dragged view's *original* position to it's new position. When adding a *new* view (for instance the placeholder gets created every time it changes position) it fades in instead.

**Analysis:**
From the looks of it, the container is remembering the view that was removed and so when the same view is added again, the animator interprets it as a move as opposed to a new view being added.

**Question:**
How can I prevent this behavior of the animator interpreting removing and adding the same child as a movement as opposed to separate remove and add operations?

**Answer:**
This is where you come in.

Thanks in advance.